# SSH dynamic port

Tags: c#, ssh, putty

I am using the Tamir dll to create a ssh tunnel to a server.
How can i create a dynamic port on that tunnel like i can do on putty.

```
Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
```

Thanks